# Q: Draw an arc on map between to marker?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to draw an arc between react-native-map markers.

Something like this:
[image]

and I couldn't do that with `<Polyline/>` and `<Circle/>`.

Any Idea How to do this?

Comment: Do you already have answer for this question?

Comment: Unfortunately, NO!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer. I had to implement this for an app I'm working on so thought I'd share the solution.

On src/utils/map.ts

```
interface LatLng {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
}

const degreesToRadians = (degrees: number) => {
  const pi = Math.PI;
  return degrees * (pi / 180);
};

const radiansToDegrees = (radians: number) => {
  const pi = Math.PI;
  return radians * (180 / pi);
};

const wrap = (n: number, min: number, max: number) => {
  return n >= min && n < max ? n : mod(n - min, max - min) + min;
};

const mod = (x: number, m: number) => {
  return ((x % m) + m) % m;
};

const EARTH_RADIUS = 6371009;

const computeDistance = (startLocation: LatLng, endLocation: LatLng) => {
  const computeDistanceRadians = (lat1: number, lng1: number, lat2: number, lng2: number) => {
    const hav = (num: number) => {
      const sinHalf = Math.sin(num * 0.5);
      return sinHalf * sinHalf;
    };

    const arcHav = (num: number) => {
      return 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(num));
    };

    const havDistance = (lat1: number, lat2: number, dLng: number) => {
      return hav(lat1 - lat2) + hav(dLng) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    };

    return arcHav(havDistance(lat1, lat2, lng1 - lng2));
  };

  const computeAngleBetween = (startLocation: LatLng, endLocation: LatLng) => {
    return computeDistanceRadians(
      degreesToRadians(startLocation.latitude),
      degreesToRadians(startLocation.longitude),
      degreesToRadians(endLocation.latitude),
      degreesToRadians(endLocation.longitude),
    );
  };

  return computeAngleBetween(startLocation, endLocation) * EARTH_RADIUS;
};

const computeHeading = (startLocation: LatLng, endLocation: LatLng) => {
  const fromLat = degreesToRadians(startLocation.latitude);
  const fromLng = degreesToRadians(startLocation.longitude);
  const toLat = degreesToRadians(endLocation.latitude);
  const toLng = degreesToRadians(endLocation.longitude);
  const dLng = toLng - fromLng;
  const heading = Math.atan2(Math.sin(dLng) * Math.cos(toLat), Math.cos(fromLat) * Math.sin(toLat) - Math.sin(fromLat) * Math.cos(toLat) * Math.cos(dLng));

  return wrap(radiansToDegrees(heading), -180, 180);
};

const computeOffset = (startLocation: LatLng, distance: number, heading: number): LatLng => {
  const d = distance / EARTH_RADIUS;
  const h = degreesToRadians(heading);
  const fromLat = degreesToRadians(startLocation.latitude);
  const fromLng = degreesToRadians(startLocation.longitude);
  const cosDistance = Math.cos(d);
  const sinDistance = Math.sin(d);
  const sinFromLat = Math.sin(fromLat);
  const cosFromLat = Math.cos(fromLat);
  const sinLat = cosDistance * sinFromLat + sinDistance * cosFromLat * Math.cos(h);
  const dLng = Math.atan2(sinDistance * cosFromLat * Math.sin(h), cosDistance - sinFromLat * sinLat);
  return {
    latitude: radiansToDegrees(Math.asin(sinLat)),
    longitude: radiansToDegrees(fromLng + dLng),
  };
};

const getDirection = (startLocation: LatLng, endLocation: LatLng) => {
  let radians = Math.atan2(endLocation.longitude - startLocation.longitude, endLocation.latitude - startLocation.latitude);
  if (radians < 0) {
    radians = radians + 2 * Math.PI;
  }

  const degree = radiansToDegrees(radians);
  const val = Math.floor(degree / 22.5 + 0.5);
  const directions = ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW'];
  return directions[val % 16];
};

export const drawArcPolyline = (startLocation: LatLng, endLocation: LatLng, curveLine: number = 0.3) => {
  const result: LatLng[] = [];

  // Curve line - set this between 0.2 to 0.5 for better results
  const k = curveLine;

  const d = computeDistance(startLocation, endLocation);
  const h = computeHeading(startLocation, endLocation);

  // Calculate the midpoint
  const p = computeOffset(startLocation, d * 0.5, h);

  // Calcualte the position of the circle center
  const x = ((1 - k * k) * d * 0.5) / (2 * k);
  const r = ((1 + k * k) * d * 0.5) / (2 * k);
  const direction = getDirection(startLocation, endLocation);
  const angle = direction === 'W' || direction === 'NW' || direction === 'WNW' || direction === 'SW' || direction === 'WSW' ? -90 : 90;
  const c = computeOffset(p, x, h + angle);

  // Calculate the heading between center of the circle and two points
  const h1 = computeHeading(c, startLocation);
  const h2 = computeHeading(c, endLocation);

  const numpoints = 100.0;
  const step = (h2 - h1) / numpoints;

  for (let i = 0; i < numpoints; i++) {
    const pi = computeOffset(c, r, h1 + i * step);
    result.push(pi);
  }
  result.push(endLocation);

  return result;
};
```

and then to implement it - it's simply:

```
<>
<Polyline
  coordinates={drawArcPolyline(
    {
      latitude: startingDestination.latitude,
      longitude: startingDestination.longitude,
    },
    {
      latitude: endingDestination.latitude,
      longitude: endingDestination.longitude,
    },
  )}
  geodesic
  strokeWidth={3}
  fillColor={'#000'}
  strokeColor={'#000'}
/>
{/* This second polyline is for a shadow effect */}
<Polyline
  coordinates={[
    {
      latitude: startingDestination.latitude,
      longitude: startingDestination.longitude,
    },
    {
      latitude: endingDestination.latitude,
      longitude: endingDestination.longitude,
    },
  ]}
  geodesic
  strokeWidth={3}
  fillColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'}
  strokeColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'}
/>
</>
```

I personally added another polyline that's straight to give a 3d effect. The result looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of Pigeon App]

Best of luck with your project :)